# How to set visibility of Footer section depending if it is a main report or subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, hide, footer, subreport

How can I hide the footer section in a *JasperReport* when it is a subreport? It should only show the footer section when it is a main report.

Answer (score 1):

Jasper Reports uses what they call Print When expressions (if I am not mistaken). It has been a while since I have used it, but each section of the report has a print when expression that you can put a statement to return true or false. So it can check a condition and then decide to show or hide a section. Each subreport also has a print when expression.

My print when expressions are generally in the format of:

```
( <THE CONDITION TO CHECK> ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE )
```

The condition can use parameters or values from a column in the report. It is pretty flexible.

There are a couple of very similar questions on SO related to Print When Expressions in Jasper Reports that may also be helpful to you:

[How to use printWhenExpression in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294989/how-to-use-print-when-expression-in-jasper)

[Inclusion and exclusion of subreports (iReport-JasperReports)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370454/inclusion-and-exclusion-of-subreports-ireport-jasper)